# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I want my fields to be editable in sitecore (supports page editors). I am using MVC 4.0 and Glass Mapper to map the fields.
After reading article [Page Editing in MVC](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial14/tutorial14.html) , I used

```
 @inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<My Model Class>
```

to get the >@Editable in my Partial view but when I use inherits keyword, my page gets below error message

```
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
```

Could someone please suggest how to @Editable keyword to edit my fields in Sitecore with MVC 4.0 and Glass Mapper version - 3.0.10.23.
Other version are

Glass.Mapper.Sc version - 3.2.0.39

Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc version - 3.2.0.34

My View looks like below

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Test.Libraries.Sitecore.Glass.Mapper.Common;
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Test.Libraries.Sitecore.Glass.Mapper.Common.Footer>

   <h2>@Editable(x=>x.Title)</h2>

 View which works is

@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Test.Libraries.Sitecore.Glass.Mapper.Common;
@model Footer

   @Model.PageTitle
```

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Which version of the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc nuget package did you download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a binding redirect from MVC 3 -> MVC 4...

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Add to the web.config of your web project (assuming that's possible with sitecore?).